# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cant find symbol

Tags: java, variables, runtimeexception

I am new programming with Java and I have found an error that I haven't been able to solve. I have revised all my code multiple times and I don't seem to find any mistake (It could be also that I'm not really experienced with the language :/ ). When trying to run my code, this is what the console shows me

*"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TaxReturn
  location: class taxReturnTester .... "*

I can see the error is because of my variable "TaxReturn" but besides changing an initial capitalization mistake, I don't see what else is wrong with it!!

This is my code:

```
package taxreturn;


public class TaxReturn {

    public TaxReturn (double anIncome, int aStatus){

    income=anIncome;
    status = aStatus;


}

public double getTax (){
    double tax = 0;

    if (status == Single ){
        if (income <= Single_Bracket1)
            tax = Rate1 * income;
            else if  ( income <= Single_Bracket2)
            tax = Rate1 * Single_Bracket1 + Rate2*(income - Single_Bracket1);
        else 
            tax = Rate1 * Single_Bracket1 + Rate2 * (Single_Bracket2 - 
Single_Bracket1) + Rate3 * (income - Single_Bracket2);

    else 

            if (income<= Married_Bracket1)
                tax=Rate1 * income; 
            else if (income <= Married_Bracket2)
                tax= Rate1 * Married_Bracket1 + Rate2 * (income - 
Married_Bracket1); 

            else 
                tax = Rate1 * Married_Bracket1 + Rate2 * ( Married_Bracket2 - 
Married_Bracket1) + Rate3 * (income - Married_Bracket2);

    }

        return tax; 

public static final int Single = 1;
public static final int Married = 2; 
private static final double Rate1= 0.5;
private static final double Rate2= 0.25;
private static final double Rate3= 0.75;
private static final double Single_Bracket1= 21450;
private static final double Single_Bracket2= 51900;
private static final double Married_Bracket1= 35000;
private static final double Married_Bracket2= 86800;
private double income;
private int status; 



import java.util.Scanner;
public class taxReturnTester {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter your Income:");
    double income = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter S (single) M (Married): ");
    String input = in.next();

// CHECK POINT 

System.out.println("Check point1");

int status= 0;

if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
    status= TaxReturn.single;
else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
    status = TaxReturn.married; 
else 
    System.out.println("Wrong Input. Please do it again");

return;
}
}
TaxReturn aTaxReturn = new TaxReturn(income,status);

System.out.println ("The tax is" + aTaxReturn.getTax() );
```

Comment: You haven't imported your `TaxReturn` in your `taxReturnTester `

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 package taxreturn;


 import java.util.Scanner;   // on top


  public  class TaxReturn {
  // only one public class per file


  public static final int Single = 1;
  public static final int Married = 2;
  private static final double Rate1= 0.5;
  private static final double Rate2= 0.25;
  private static final double Rate3= 0.75;
  private static final double Single_Bracket1= 21450;
  private static final double Single_Bracket2= 51900;
  private static final double Married_Bracket1= 35000;
  private static final double Married_Bracket2= 86800;

  private double income;
  private int status;



public TaxReturn (double anIncome, int aStatus){
income=anIncome;
status = aStatus;
 }

  public double getTax (){
      double tax = 0;

if (status == Single ){
    if (income <= Single_Bracket1)

        tax = Rate1 * income;
        else if  ( income <= Single_Bracket2)
        tax = Rate1 * Single_Bracket1 + Rate2*(income - Single_Bracket1);
    else
        tax = Rate1 * Single_Bracket1 + Rate2 * (Single_Bracket2 -             Single_Bracket1) + Rate3 * (income - Single_Bracket2);
    }  // added

else

        if (income<= Married_Bracket1)
            tax=Rate1 * income;
        else if (income <= Married_Bracket2)
            tax= Rate1 * Married_Bracket1 + Rate2 * (income -
  Married_Bracket1);

        else
            tax = Rate1 * Married_Bracket1 + Rate2 * ( Married_Bracket2 -
  Married_Bracket1) + Rate3 * (income - Married_Bracket2);

    // not here  }

    return tax;
  } // ends getTax

 } // added, ends class


  // import java.util.Scanner; not here
   class taxReturnTester {

public static void main (String [] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Please Enter your Income:");
double income = in.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Please enter S (single) M (Married): ");
String input = in.next();

  // CHECK POINT

  System.out.println("Check point1");

  int status= 0;

  if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      status= TaxReturn.Single;           // upcase
  else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
      status = TaxReturn.Married;          // upcase
  else
  {  // added

System.out.println("Wrong Input. Please do it again");
  return;
  }  // added
   TaxReturn aTaxReturn = new TaxReturn(income,status);
    System.out.println ("The tax is: " + aTaxReturn.getTax() ); // added space
    }  // ends main
  }  // ends class

// not out any classes
// TaxReturn aTaxReturn = new TaxReturn(income,status);
// System.out.println ("The tax is" + aTaxReturn.getTax() );
```

Comment: Don't post code only answers. Please add some explanation to your answer, it will be helpful for the future visitors.